# XSLT: How to select elements that are unique to an ancestor (not the root)?

Tags: xslt, sorting, key

I'm looking for a way to select a unique set of nodes from an ancestor element below the root.  My simplified input looks like this (Note: there may be several `<Single>` and `<Multi>` elements in a `<Package>`):

```
<Package>
  <Single>
    <Patient>
      <Drug>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Dose>1 tab</Dose>
      </Drug>
      <Drug>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
      </Drug>
    </Patient>
  </Single>
  <Multi>
    <Patient>
      <Drug>
        <Name>A</Name>
        <Dose>1 tab</Dose>
      </Drug>
      <Drug>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
      </Drug>
      <Drug>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <Dose>3 drops</Dose>
      </Drug>
    </Patient>
    <Patient>
      <Drug>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
      </Drug>
      <Drug>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
      </Drug>
      <Drug>
        <Name>C</Name>
        <Dose>3 drops</Dose>
      </Drug>
      <Drug>
        <Name>D</Name>
        <Dose>4 glasses</Dose>
      </Drug>
    </Patient>
  </Multi>
</Package>
```

I'd like to select the Drugs that are unique for each `<Single>` or `<Multi>` element accross `<Patient>`s.  So far I have:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="Package/Single | Package/Multi">
      <xsl:call-template name="SO" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="uniqueKey" match="//Patient/Drug" use="concat(Name, Dose)" />

  <xsl:template name="SO">
    <UniquePerMultiOrSingle>
      <xsl:for-each select="//Patient/Drug[
                              generate-id() =
                              generate-id(key('uniqueKey', concat(Name, Dose))[1])]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Dose"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </UniquePerMultiOrSingle>
  </xsl:template>
```

The output looks like this:

```
<UniquePerMultiOrSingle>
  <Name>A</Name>
  <Dose>1 tab</Dose>
  <Name>B</Name>
  <Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
  <Name>C</Name>
  <Dose>3 drops</Dose>
  <Name>D</Name>
  <Dose>4 glasses</Dose>
</UniquePerMultiOrSingle>
<UniquePerMultiOrSingle>
  <Name>A</Name>
  <Dose>1 tab</Dose>
  <Name>B</Name>
  <Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
  <Name>C</Name>
  <Dose>3 drops</Dose>
  <Name>D</Name>
  <Dose>4 glasses</Dose>
</UniquePerMultiOrSingle>
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
<UniquePerMultiOrSingle>
  <Name>A</Name>
  <Dose>1 tab</Dose>
  <Name>B</Name>
  <Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
</UniquePerMultiOrSingle>
<UniquePerMultiOrSingle>
  <Name>A</Name>
  <Dose>1 tab</Dose>
  <Name>B</Name>
  <Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
  <Name>C</Name>
  <Dose>3 drops</Dose>
  <Name>D</Name>
  <Dose>4 glasses</Dose>
</UniquePerMultiOrSingle>
```

My question: is there a way to select `<Drug>`s that are unique **per `<Single>` or `<Multi>` element only** (not the whole document)?  If not, is there any other way to achieve this?  I'm using xslt 1.0.

Comment: As an aside making Name and Dose siblings to other Name and Dose elements feels really icky too me and makes it less data-like and less queryable.  I would suggest you keep the Drug parent with the Dose and Names as children to that parent.

Comment: I agree.  The output is simplified to illustrate what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPackageDrugsByName" match="Drug"
  use="concat(generate-id(../..), '+', Name, '+', Dose)"/>

 <xsl:template match="Single | Multi">
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> -- Drugs:&#xA;<xsl:text/>

  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "*/Drug
       [generate-id()
       =
        generate-id(key('kPackageDrugsByName',
                        concat(generate-id(../..),
                               '+', Name, '+', Dose)
                       )[1]
                   )
       ]/*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Package>
    <Single>
        <Patient>
            <Drug>
                <Name>A</Name>
                <Dose>1 tab</Dose>
            </Drug>
            <Drug>
                <Name>B</Name>
                <Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
            </Drug>
        </Patient>
    </Single>
    <Multi>
        <Patient>
            <Drug>
                <Name>A</Name>
                <Dose>1 tab</Dose>
            </Drug>
            <Drug>
                <Name>B</Name>
                <Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
            </Drug>
            <Drug>
                <Name>C</Name>
                <Dose>3 drops</Dose>
            </Drug>
        </Patient>
        <Patient>
            <Drug>
                <Name>B</Name>
                <Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
            </Drug>
            <Drug>
                <Name>B</Name>
                <Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
            </Drug>
            <Drug>
                <Name>C</Name>
                <Dose>3 drops</Dose>
            </Drug>
            <Drug>
                <Name>D</Name>
                <Dose>4 glasses</Dose>
            </Drug>
        </Patient>
    </Multi>
</Package>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
Single -- Drugs:
<Name>A</Name>
<Dose>1 tab</Dose>
<Name>B</Name>
<Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>

Multi -- Drugs:
<Name>A</Name>
<Dose>1 tab</Dose>
<Name>B</Name>
<Dose>2 spoonfuls</Dose>
<Name>C</Name>
<Dose>3 drops</Dose>
<Name>D</Name>
<Dose>4 glasses</Dose>
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks!  The lesson learned for me is using a relative path for generate-id in the definition of the key.  I'll boost your response.